# Tail-Loop Puzzle with a Linked list - My Python solution is Failing when tail is longer than loop

Tags: python, loops, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have been working on a puzzle on codewars that can be found here:

http://www.codewars.com/kata/can-you-get-the-loop

Basically, the input is the first node of a linked list which is guaranteed to have a tail of some length and a loop of some length. (For a picture see the link.)

My solution is to have two iterators step through the list, one that visits every node and one that skips every node.  Once they hit, I know I am inside the loop, so I just count one cycle and return the count.

Here is my code:

```
def loop_size(node):
    size = 1
    onestep = node
    twostep = node.next
    while(onestep != twostep):
        twostep = twostep.next.next
        onestep = onestep.next
    #we are inside the loop
    #onestep == twostep
    onestep = node.next
    size += 1
    while(onestep != twostep):
        size += 1
        onestep = onestep.next
    return size
```

For some reason I am getting odd results.  Whenever the tail is smaller than the loop, I get the correct result.  But whenever the tail is longer than or equal to the size of the loop, my function gets a way higher count.

Here are some examples:

```
Tail length = 1 Loop Length = 3
###result 3 - correct

Tail length = 999 Loop Length = 1000
###result 1000 - correct

Tail length = 1000 Loop Length = 999
###result 1998 - incorrect

Tail length = 50 Loop Length = 3
###result 51 - incorrect

Tail length = 3 Loop Length = 3
###result 6 - incorrect

Tail length = 3 Loop Length = 4
###result 4 - correct
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line

```
onestep = node.next
```

should be

```
onestep = onestep.next
```

Otherwise you are starting from the head again and re-entering the loop so your results will be the tail length too long.  Also, I believe your size should be started as 1, not 2 as you have it (size = 1, size += 1 before the second loop starts).

This code works for all of your examples:

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, next_node=None):
        self.next_node = next_node

    @property
    def next(self):
        return self.next_node

    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next_node = new_next
        return new_next

def loop_size(node):
    onestep = node
    twostep = node.next
    while(onestep != twostep):
        twostep = twostep.next.next
        onestep = onestep.next
    onestep = onestep.next
    size = 1
    while(onestep != twostep):
        size += 1
        onestep = onestep.next
    return size

def test_ll(tail, loop):
    head = Node()
    nodes = [head]
    for i in range(2, tail+loop+1):
        head = head.set_next(Node())
        nodes.append(head)
    nodes[-1].set_next(nodes[tail])
    size = loop_size(nodes[0])
    print "Tail: {}, Loop: {}, Size: {}".format(tail, loop, size)

test_ll(1, 3)
test_ll(999, 1000)
test_ll(1000, 999)
test_ll(50, 3)
test_ll(3, 3)
test_ll(3, 4)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Tail: 1, Loop: 3, Size: 3
Tail: 999, Loop: 1000, Size: 1000
Tail: 1000, Loop: 999, Size: 999
Tail: 50, Loop: 3, Size: 3
Tail: 3, Loop: 3, Size: 3
Tail: 3, Loop: 4, Size: 4
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes so much sense now.